# Gulp SASS Not Compiling @import Changes

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

We're running Gulp 4 and have one main scss file that pulls in a partial via @import. For example: `app.scss`, and `app.scss` has one line in it, `@import "partials/_mypartial.scss";`.

We also have a task running called, `styles`, that we're currently running manually via `gulp styles` as we troubleshoot this issue.

The issue is, if we make a change directly to `app.scss`, as in we add more `@import` partials, or we update the comments within the file, `gulp-sass` works perfectly  and compiles the `.css` file as intended.

However, if all we do is update the partial file (and nothing changes in `app.scss`), i.e., a mixin or declaration, `gulp-sass` is not pulling the updates when running the `styles` task.

What ends up happening is the `css` file is created and placed in dest directory with the same timestamp as when `app.scss` was last "processed" but without the changes made to the partial file.

We're not telling gulp-sass to cache anything and are using default settings. Any idea why this is occurring when updating the partial file ONLY?

Directory structure:

`/assets/src/scss/app.scss`
`/assets/src/scss/partials/_mypartial.scss`

app.scss contents: `@import "partials/mypartial";`
_mypartial.scss contents: `.row { margin-left: -35px; }`

NOTE: These are test files to troubleshoot the issue. If all we do is touch _mypartial.scss, i.e., change the margin-left to some other value, running `gulp style` manually does not pick up the change. If we touch app.scss, then the _mypartial.scss changes get picked up as desired.

Gulpfile snippets:

```
gulp.task('styles-build-sass', function () {
  return buildSass(config.styles.postcss);
});

gulp.task(
  'styles',
  gulp.series(
    'styles-clean-entry',
    'styles-build-sass',
    'styles-minify',
    'styles-staging',
    'styles-clean-exit',
  )
);

function buildSass(settings)
{
  return gulp

  .src(settings.src)

  .pipe(plugins.plumber({
    errorHandler: handleErrors
  }))

  .pipe(plugins.sass({
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded
  }))

  // Create *.css.
  .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.dest)).on('end', function () {
    plugins.log((plugins.colors.symbols.check) + " " + 
    (plugins.colors.bold.green.underline('Stage 2: Sass has been 
    compiled into native CSS ... [buildSass()]')));
  })

}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your gulpfile?

Comment: I'm running the task manually, i.e., `gulp styles`, from the CLI necessary to troubleshoot this issue for now. I've updated the Question above with more information as well.

Comment: A year later and I am having this exact same problem. Did you ever find a real solution? I noticed you closed your own issue on the gulp-sass Github repo. My workaround for the moment is just to put in some dummy change that will force recompliation and then delete that change and resave.

Comment: Same here, @cjl750. Could you solve this issue?

Comment: @Dong3000 I pulled up the project I was working on when I made that comment, and the gulp-sass stuff seems to be working just fine with partials. Unfortunately I'm not sure what to offer in the way of an answer because I don't really remember what I ended up doing, and I don't see any commits that clearly offer a solution to the problem. I can tell you I was using gulp-ruby-sass before and changed to gulp-sass, which required a slight syntax change in the Gulp task, which may have been my issue. If you're also upgrading from gulp-ruby-sass, I'd say just read the gulp-sass docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided contents of your `gulpfile.js` and I don't know your directories structure - here is who assumptions that I've made from your questions:

1. I suppose that you have watching task for SCSS that looks something like this:
   `gulp.watch('styles/*.scss', ['styles']);`
2. I suppose that your partials are stored into subdirectories against main SCSS file

If my assumptions are correct - then answer is quite simple. Please notice that glob definition, is `styles/*.scss`. It means "all files with `.scss` extensions that **directly** resides into directory `styles`". Since partials are stored into subdirectories - they simply didn't match this glob and hence didn't being watched.

Fix is also quite simple - you need to update your watching glob to include subdirectories: `styles/**/*.scss`

Comment: I'm running the task manually, i.e., `gulp styles`, from the CLI necessary to troubleshoot this issue for now. I've updated the Question above with more information as well.

Comment: @GregoryMatthews What is in `settings.src` that you're passing in `gulp.src`?

Comment: It's basically just `srcDirs.scss + '*.scss'`. I've also tried it as `srcDirs.scss + '**/*.scss'` as well. `srsDirs` resolves to `/assets/src/scss`.

Comment: Isn't it should be `srcDirs.scss + '/*.scss'`? Otherwise you end up with an invalid path

Comment: No because all I'm doing is pulling in `app.scss` and again, when I run this manually, everything works. The issue is, if all I do is make a change to `mypartial.scss` without touching `app.scss`, the changes made to `mypartial.scss` are not seen in the resulting `.css` file (even though `app.scss` pulls this in via `@import`). If I touch `app.scss`, then the changes made to `mypartial.scss` show up. I'm not sure why gulp sass is not simply recompiling everything defined regardless of whether or not the file is "touched".

Comment: It is indeed strange. Looks like some cache issue, but `node-sass` have no cache by itself. Or maybe you're using different implementation e.g. Ruby (that have its own cache)? I would try to comment out whole code and start over again with minimal working example that can be found in [gulp-sass docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass#basic-usage). If it will work - then problem is in your `gulpfile.js`, if not - it is somewhere else, but it may be a good starting point

Comment: 10-4. I thought of the caching issue also but couldn't find a setting anywhere. I'll start breaking it down. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, after much testing, I found that the partials are now being updated when changing comments and/or class names, i.e., `.row` to `.row1`, but when changing the class numerical values, i.e., `margin-left: 25px;` to `margin-left: 15px;`, the changes are not getting picked up when only touching the partial. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: When I change `margin-left` value via SASS variable, it works perfectly. I guess SASS doesn't recognize @import partial updates when the changes are already in css in lieu of SASS?

Comment: It is not an expected behavior. Maybe it worth trying to run [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) directly, not through Gulp to see if problem is in Sass compiler or Gulp? You may also consider to try [dart-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass) instead